# Change the Woocommerce breadcrumb link

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the following snippet to change the URL but I want to make it dynamic rather than hard coding a link in.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_home_url', 'woo_custom_breadrumb_home_url' );
function woo_custom_breadrumb_home_url() {
    return 'http://woothemes.com';
}
```

I tried the following which not only breaks the link but it appears in the top of the screen.

```
$breadcrumb = bloginfo('url');
add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_home_url', 'woo_custom_breadrumb_home_url' );
function woo_custom_breadrumb_home_url() {
    return '$breadcrumb';
}
```

**How can I make the Home link dynamic?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
return home_url();
```

This should give you the same address as bloginfo('url')

Comment: Great, thanks. Had to add a little bit inside that but it works - `return home_url('/shop');`